# Rest Assured access last element in list using JsonPath

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to use RestAssured to test an endpoint that returns a JSON list of objects. How can I verify the contents of the last object in the list using RestAssured JsonPath?

Example return value:

```
[
 {
    "foo": "bar"
 },
 {
    "foo": "brazz"
 } 
]
```

I tried using negative indices:
`body("[-1].foo", equalTo("brazz"))` but that does not work, as Rest assured considers `"[-1].foo"` to be an empty list.

How can I access the last element of a list with JsonPath Syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `last()` to get the last item.

```
body("last().foo", equalTo("brazz"))
```